# Oracle orderBy matching complementary values

Tags: oracle, sql-order-by

I have a table with the following content

| ID | NAME | SIZE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PACKAGE A | 3 |
| 2 | PACKAGE B | 2 |
| 3 | PACKAGE C | 1 |
| 4 | PACKAGE D | 2 |
| 5 | PACKAGE E | 5 |

Now i would like to order them so that the sum of two directly successive packages shall correspond to the value '4'.

In the case of the table above a right result could look like this:

| ID | NAME | SIZE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PACKAGE A | 3 |
| 2 | PACKAGE C | 1 |
| 3 | PACKAGE B | 2 |
| 4 | PACKAGE D | 2 |
| 5 | PACKAGE E | 5 |

My question is if this is possible with Oracle SQL functions and if so how someone would realise this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `PIPELINED` function to get the pairs.

First create the types:

```sql
CREATE TYPE table_name__obj AS OBJECT(
  id     NUMBER,
  name   VARCHAR2(20),
  "SIZE" NUMBER
);

CREATE TYPE table_name__tbl AS TABLE OF table_name__obj;
```

And then the function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION paired_products(
  v_total IN PLS_INTEGER
) RETURN table_name__tbl PIPELINED
IS
  v_tbl table_name__tbl;
  i     PLS_INTEGER;
  i_nxt PLS_INTEGER;
  j     PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT table_name__obj(id, name, "SIZE")
  BULK COLLECT INTO v_tbl
  FROM   table_name
  ORDER BY "SIZE";
  
  i := v_tbl.FIRST;
  WHILE i IS NOT NULL LOOP
    j := v_tbl.NEXT(i);
    WHILE j IS NOT NULL LOOP
      IF v_tbl(i)."SIZE" + v_tbl(j)."SIZE" = v_total THEN
        EXIT;
      END IF;
      j := v_tbl.NEXT(j);
    END LOOP;

    PIPE ROW(v_tbl(i));
    IF j IS NOT NULL THEN
      PIPE ROW(v_tbl(j));
      v_tbl.DELETE(j);
    END IF;

    i_nxt := v_tbl.NEXT(i);
    v_tbl.DELETE(i);
    i := i_nxt;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID, NAME, "SIZE") AS
SELECT 1, 'PACKAGE A', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'PACKAGE B', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'PACKAGE C', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'PACKAGE D', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'PACKAGE E', 5 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs the rows in the order starting from the smallest size and the corresponding pair and then in increasing sized pairs. If a row is found that does not have a matching pair then it is output immediately it is found not to have a pair.

> | ID | NAME | SIZE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 3 | PACKAGE C | 1 |
> | 1 | PACKAGE A | 3 |
> | 2 | PACKAGE B | 2 |
> | 4 | PACKAGE D | 2 |
> | 5 | PACKAGE E | 5 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=74928bf944781459cf1d62e0e0f5af51)*

Comment: Wow that was fast. 
Thank you very much.